# printing the values of an Array prevents a null pointer error

Tags: python, arrays, debugging, nonetype

I'm trying to search a parameter space for a good model. In my code I'm doing something like the following:

```
configurations = [None] * 9
index = 0
for param1 in range(3):
  for param2 in range (3):
    #call constructor
    configurations[index] = Configuration(param1, param2) 
    index = index + 1
return configurations
```

then I use this array elsewhere to build the models.
However, for some reason it doesn't fill the array. I get an error when accessing index 3 or higher. Inspection shows that the array at these indices are still 'None'. while debugging this, I added a print statement to the code:

```
configurations = [None] * 9
index = 0
for param1 in range(3):
  for param2 in range (3):
    #call constructor
    configurations[index] = Configuration(param1, param2)
    index = index + 1

for x in configurations:
  print(x.param1)
return configurations
```

to my surprise, my code now ran smoothly. The array is completely filled. If I comment out those 2 lines: error. uncomment the lines: it works again.

what is going on here? Why is the print statement altering the behavior of my program? is this an overactive GC that's staved off by printing the values?

Comment: "something like the following" - could you elaborate? Is it possible that in your original code, you have a generator somewhere? Generators are lazily evaluated, so only when you iterate over it, the real value is calculated.

Comment: That is interesting, but I'm directly calling a contructor inside the for-loops. I will edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: Could you try printing the `configurations` before the double loop, then after it (but before the print loop)? And show the print results?

Comment: I found the bug. the last return statement was indented with a Tab, but I use 4 spaces. This was causing it to skip the most outer for loop. the print statement somehow prevented this. changing the tab to spaces removed the need for the print statement. unbelievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. the return statement was indented with a Tab, but I use 4 spaces everywhere else in my code. This was causing it to skip the most outer for loop. the print statement somehow prevented this. changing the tab to spaces removed the need for the print statement.